# R Highcharter - shared tooltip (and various tooltip arguments) not working

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I'm trying to use highcharter to plot some time-series data:

```
volumes <- structure(list(priorDate = structure(c(18125, 18126, 18127, 18128, 
18129, 18130), class = "Date"), s_1_1 = c(18481L, 18503L, 18247L, 
17994L, 17755L, 17506L), s_1_2 = c(83143L, 83129L, 83160L, 83171L, 
83120L, 83107L), s_1_3 = c(74456L, 74487L, 74510L, 74549L, 74614L, 
74633L), s_1_4 = c(240095L, 240242L, 240416L, 240604L, 240776L, 
241006L), s_2_10 = c(44542L, 44600L, 44605L, 44665L, 44749L, 
44827L), s_2_11 = c(183468L, 183565L, 183628L, 183692L, 183706L, 
183794L), s_2_5 = c(1400L, 1394L, 1415L, 1406L, 1462L, 1415L), 
    s_2_6 = c(1063L, 1041L, 1046L, 1050L, 1093L, 1051L), s_2_7 = c(38073L, 
    38066L, 38021L, 37936L, 37929L, 37875L), s_2_8 = c(19175L, 
    19156L, 19248L, 19345L, 19420L, 19502L), s_2_9 = c(44103L, 
    44052L, 44029L, 43939L, 43817L, 43747L)), row.names = 1:6, class = "data.frame")
```

I'm having a lot of trouble customising the tooltip.  My goal is to have the tooltip display the data for all series.  I thought this would do the trick:

```
highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_add_series(volumes, type = 'line', hcaes(x = priorDate, y = s_1_1), name = 'Prime Enquirer') %>%
  hc_add_series(volumes, type = 'line', hcaes(x = priorDate, y = s_1_2), name = 'Active Enquirer') %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = 'date') %>%
  hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE)
```

But this plots in exactly the same fashion as without `hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE)`.
I am also unable to get the chart to display a legend. I have to assume I'm being an idiot and missing something really simple.

I'd appreciate any help; this has been annoying me for a while.

Comment: to show legend, add `hc_legend(enabled = TRUE)` - as for tooltip, it looks like it does show both series data (Active and Prime) with hover...maybe i'm confused - what tooltip behavior are you missing?

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the tip about the legend.  Sorry, should've been clearer; I want the tooltip to display a single box with all series data contained ( this is what I had thought the 'shared = TRUE'  argument would accomplish)

Comment: can you try adding `split = FALSE` to your `hc_tooltip` statement?